# Fitting a regression line in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can i fit a regression line of the following  plot ?

```
  data = [1 72 134 3.2; 2 81 201 3.5; 3 60 156 7.1; 4 82 148 2.4; 5 75 176 1.2]
  rate=data(:,2)
  weight = data(:,3)
  hour = data(:,4)
  scatter3(rate,weight,hour,'filled')
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: It's a three-dimensional plot, so you can't fit a regression *line* to it. Which variables are the independent ones, and which is dependent (i.e. what variable do you want to predict from the other ones?)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Heart rate is the dependent variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [1 72 134 3.2; 2 81 201 3.5; 3 60 156 7.1; 4 82 148 2.4; 5 75 176 1.2] ;
rate=data(:,2) ;
weight = data(:,3) ;
hour = data(:,4) ;
% Regression 
A = [ones(size(weight)), weight , hour];
coeff = A \ rate ; % Thanks to Andreas!  
% Plot data points
figure(1);clf;
scatter3(weight,hour,rate,'filled') ;hold on
% Plot plane
weightLim = [min(weight) max(weight)];
hourLim = [min(hour) max(hour)];
[x1, x2] = meshgrid(weightLim,hourLim);
Z = coeff(1) + coeff(2)*x1 + coeff(3)*x2 ; 
surf(x1,x2,Z)
```

Comment: is it `coeff` in place of `coef` in the 2nd line of the bottom ?

Comment: Note, that the explicit computation of the pseudoinverse is not recommended in Matlab for accuracy (and maybe speed) reasons. In fact the line "coeff = (A' * A) \ A' * rate ; " can be replaced by "coeff = A \ rate ;" the backslash operator will just do the right thing.

Comment: Hello Andreas, thanks for your comment. You are absolutely right. The backslash operator will use the pseudo inverse if its needed. I mistakenly directly applied the well-known closed-form regression formula.

Answer (score 0):

You need a regression line?

Here is a least-squares estimate:

```
y = rate;
X = [data(:, 3:4) ones(numel(y), 1)];
[b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(y, X);
```

or

```
b = (X'*X)^(-1)*X'*y
```

Hopefully you have more than five points …

Comment: What is Y in numel() ?